# Кодировка или фильтрация url запросов в меню yii2, как исправить?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

В меню Nav::widget прописываю раздел меню:

```
[
    'label' => 'My profile',
    'url' => [ '/profile/professional&id='.$userlog->id ]
],
```

Появляется ссылка, при наведении на нее вижу, что ссылка верная и перейдет по адресу:

```
/index.php?r=profile/professional&id=22
```

Жму на нее, переходит по адресу:

```
/index.php?r=profile%2Fprofessional%26id%3D22
```

Разумеется, он пишет, что страница не найдена. Правлю все эти %2F и т.п. на нужные символы - страница находится.

Сохраняю файл с меню в кодировке utf-8, почему так происходит, как поправить?

Comment: Зачем вы вообще создаете ссылку руками?

Answer (score 3):

Исправить можно 2 способами:

1) передать URL как строку, а не как массив:

```
'url' => '/profile/professional&id='.$userlog->id
```

2) разделить маршрут и параметры:

```
'url' => [ '/profile/professional', 'id' => $userlog->id ]
```